# How to send String from php firebase notification to notification service in android?

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a notification with the string of "room" from php. this is my code:

```
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', '--------------------------' );
#prep the bundle
$msg = array (
    'body'  => $_GET['isi'],
    'title' => $nama." mengirim pesan",
    'icon'  => 'myicon',/*Default Icon*/
    'sound' => 'mySound',/*Default sound*/
    'room' => $room //This is String I want to send
);
$fields = array (
    'to'            => $registrationIds,
    'notification'  => $msg
);

$headers = array (
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
```

And I would like to receive a string of "room" here:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMessagingService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}
```

How can I get String of "room"?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`notification` message payloads only have specific parameters available for use (see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support)).

You're going to have to use a `data` message payload to add your custom key-value pair and then [handle the messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) accordingly.

Comment: Thanks.. This is very helpful